# Form::textarea в laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, forms, textarea

Привет,
Подскажите,  в laravel 5.4  при использовании форм на определении

```
{{ Form::textarea('description', isset($shippingClass->description) ? $shippingClass->description : ''), [   "class"=>"form-control editable_field textarea_input ". $viewFuncs->setFieldErrorTag($errorsList, "description", ' has-danger '), "rows"=>"5", "cols"=> 120, "placeholder"=>"Enter string description in 255 characters.", "id"=>"description"  ] }}
```

рендится код

```
<textarea name="description" cols="50" rows="10">Some Text</textarea>
```

То есть 3й параметр массив полностью не попал в исходный код
Хотя судя по найденному описанию в нете - должен.

Это лечится и если да то как?

И вообще стоит ли использовать формы ? Не булет ли дополнительно проблем?

```
Спасибо!
```